# What's the difference between a transfer pass and a boarding pass?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, layovers, airport-transfer, terminology

Looking back at some past flight tickets, I see for a trip with 1 layover, I was given a boarding pass for the first leg, and a transfer pass for the second leg. The pass type was indicated on the boarding and transfer passes. Both the boarding and the transfer passes mention the seat number as well as the boarding time.

What's the difference between a transfer pass and a boarding pass? E.g., does a transfer pass not allow me to leave/re-enter the airport during the layover?

Example of transfer and boarding passes:

[image]

The transfer pass looks the same as the boarding pass, the only difference being that it says transfer pass at the top right corner instead of boarding pass.

More information: single ticket, transit pass issued at the departure airport at the same time as the boarding pass, didn't pass immigration during layover, no visa required at layover. leave the airport" = exit the airport's secure area

Comment: Does that transfer pass give you the seat number (and if usual for the airport the gate and the closing time for the gate)?

Comment: I don’t think I’ve had a “transfer pass” in hand either (or I didn’t pay attention). In some cases when you have a connection they are not able to give you all boarding passes at the origin airport (you’ll have to get the missing ones at a transfer desk or at the gate at the connection airport), and in that case they give you something else not named a boarding pass, though I don’t remember what is stated then. Sometimes just “itinerary summary” or something similar I believe. But those cannot be used to board, you need to get an actual boarding pass. What airline and what connection airport?

Comment: "E.g., does a transfer pass not allow me to leave/re-enter the airport during the layover?"

Does a boarding pass? I think it usually has little to do with the type of pass, and more with other regulations of the country?

Comment: @Willeke Both the boarding and the transfer passes mention the seat number.

Comment: To challenge the question's assumption: perhaps there is no difference.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica no assumption made, that's valid answer.

Comment: @jcaron the transfer pass was used to board. No boarding pass was issued. I've added a picture of it in the question.

Comment: @Willeke the transit pass also indicates the boarding time

Comment: Maybe it’s some airline’s policy to name the first one “boarding pass” and subsequent ones “transfer pass” to make it easier for passengers find and use the right one? What airline was this?

Comment: A lot of airports have automatic gates. I suspect even if the transfer pass had a QR code it  would not work at the gate of the other airport. So if you want to re-enter you'll need also some spare time to ask the personnel to let you through in some way.

Comment: Perhaps the circumstances of the pass' issuance and use will help distinguish them. Single or multiple tickets? Issued at the same time or different times? Passing immigration in the layover/transfer airport(s) or not? Visa  required for the layover/transfer? Visa _actually inspected by immigration_ in these airports? When you say "leave the airport" do you mean exit the airport's secure area, so you'd have to pass through security again to get to your departure gate?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica single ticket, issued at departure airport at the same time as the boarding pass, didn't pass immigration during layover, no visa required at layover. leave the airport" = exit the airport's secure area

Comment: In this no-visa example, the two passes function identically. I think @jcaron (comment yesterday) has it correct.